# Duda sobre Pilas en C

Tags: c, pilas, stack

no puedo resolver la logica del siguiente planteo: tengo dos stacks o pilas A y B. Las dos ya tienen numeros cargados y me piden hacer una pila C con los elementos que estan en A y en B pero que no esten repetidos (union de conjuntos de A y B).

Dadas dos pilas A y B que simulan conjuntos (cada conjunto no tiene elementos repetidos sobre sí mismo), realizar un programa que calcule en la pila C la operación de unión.

Algún indicio de como hacerlo? gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, lee por favor [ask]

Comment: Tengo dos colecciones de objetos de tipo INT, A y B. Necesito pasar los elementos que estan en A y B a la coleccion C pero los mismos no se pueden repetir, ejemplo: si tengo en A un 5 y en B un 5, solamenente puede haber uno solo en C

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves y asi es mas seguro que alguien te auxilie